# Social networking on smart phones?

Tags: networking

I have to implement application that can post to the selected network I can select from the application drop down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are Objective-C frameworks for Facebook ([Three20](http://three20.info/)) and Twitter ([Twitter-OAuth-Library](https://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone) & [MGTwitterEngine](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine)).

A quick trip to Google find [facebook-android-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk) for connecting to Facebook on Android.
As far as Twitter goes, you can find [a whole list of APIs for various languages/platforms on Twitter's developer website](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_libraries).

**EDIT**

A second trip to Google finds [this on developer.myspace.com](http://wiki.developer.myspace.com/index.php?title=MySpaceID_SDK_for_iPhone) for adding MySpace to an iOS app. Also, see [this page](http://developer.linkedin.com/community/apis)  and [this page](http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1008) on [LinkedIn's Developer Network](http://developer.linkedin.com/index.jspa).
Basically, LinkedIn is just using a JSON encoded API with OAuth. You should be able to handle that with any OAuth library.

**EDIT2:**

It seems that I've found another great library. Check out [ShareKit](http://getsharekit.com/), which helps with alot of what you're trying to do.

Comment: This is really good reference. But I need to implement Myspace and LinkedIn in my application. Do you have any reference for the same. Please give your response as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

@appaspect and @moshe, this is an old thread so the question my no longer be relevant, but here's a new open-source SDK and social api service: Socialize http://www.GetSocialize.com .  Full feature set at http://go.GetSocialize.com/features

DROdio